# The results is not consistent when using a concurrent hash map

Tags: java, multithreading

> I have a class `Counter` that has multiple endpoints. I want to retain the number of "visits" for each endpoint. The endpoints can be accessed from different threads and I decided to use `ConcurrentHashMap`.

**Here is my code, I've created a class that simulates this behavior:**

```
public class Counter {

    Map<String, Integer> endpoints = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    void load(String endpoint) {

        endpoints.put(endpoint, endpoints.get(endpoint) + 1);
    }

    void accessEndpoint(String endpoint, int times, int numberOfThreads) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            executor.submit(() -> load(endpoint));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Counter counter = new Counter();
        counter.endpoints.put("www.google.com", 2);
        counter.accessEndpoint("www.google.com", 100, 10);
        System.out.println(counter.endpoints.get("www.google.com"));
    }
}
```

The output is not consistent.

Expected: 102

Actual: 95, 100, 102, 66, 100

Comment: Thread 1 (T1): get from map, value 1. T2: get from map, value 1. T1: increment and put 2 into map. T2: increment and put 2 into map. Oops.

Comment: Take a lesson here: just using concurrent collections does not magically make your code correct. Use `Map.merge`. `endpoints.merge(endpoint, 1, Integer::sum)`

Comment: I squirm to see a function named "accessEndpoint" that creates a new thread pool every time it is called. I know that the function is only called one time in this example, but it still feels [unclean](https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`endpoints.put(endpoint, endpoints.get(endpoint) + 1);` is not an atomic operation.
So two threads could `get()` the same number (say 100), and `put` the same number back (101), making two calls count as just one.

Use `compute()` instead, which *is* atomic:

```
endpoints.compute(endpoint, (k,v)-> v+1);
```

or if you want to always start with zero with no initialization.

```
endpoints.merge(endpoint, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider Point taken.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've also returned 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I know that I don't need it, I just like having having a reminder of the boxing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The first snippet is the exact translation of OP's `endpoints.put(endpoint, endpoints.get(endpoint) + 1);`, only in atomic form.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I removed the `valueOf`, although I do like having it for fixed values. Anyway, that's not important. And you can't use `Integer::sum` here since we're not adding the key to the value. So you still end up with `Integer.sum(v,1)`, which *is* unnecessary verbose compared to `v+1`